# Android Realm - use a LINK as where clause

Tags: android, realm

I have two classes

City class

```
private int id;
private String cityName;
```

Person class

```
private int id;
private String personName;
private long dob;
private City hometown;
```

I want to know how I can get a list of people who are living in a particular city

My first attempt was this

```
RealmResults <Person> people = realm.where(Person.class).equalTo("hometown", "(1, Melbourne)").findAll();
```

When I execute this line I get following error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field 'hometown': type mismatch. Was STRING, expected LINK
```

Therefore, I want to know how I can pass a LINK as the second argument in "equalTo()" method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RealmResults <Person> people = realm.where(Person.class).equalTo("hometown.cityName", "Melbourne").findAll();
```